# How to read CSV data in one column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Input: csv file that has data present in a single column of the csv file.

Ex:

```
"ftre1   ftre2"
"123     145"
```

when I use:

```
pandas.read_csv(file)
```

I get:

```
ftre1/ftre2
123/145
```

Expected would be the usual DF format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
pandas.read_csv(path, delim_whitespace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/d1', sep=' ', header=None)
print(df)
```